# Coding bat simple code logic in JAVA

Tags: java

Coding bat is a website to test the candidate's logic and reasoning abilities using JAVA or Python. I am trying the following problem and am unable to proceed:

Given a non-negative number "num", return true if num is within 2 of a multiple of 10. Note: (a % b) is the remainder of dividing a by b, so (7 % 5) is 2. See also: Introduction to Mod

nearTen(12) → true
nearTen(17) → false
nearTen(19) → true

.

The code I have written is :

```
{
public boolean nearTen(int num) {
  if (num==10 || num==1){
  return true;}
  else if (num<10){
  return false;}
  else if ((num+2)%10==0 || ((num-2)%10==0)){
  return true;}
  else if ((num+1)%10==0 || ((num-1)%10==0)){
  return true;}
  else{
  return false;}
}
}
```

Can anyone of you please tell my mistake so that I can improve on the same?

Comment: Your logic is too convoluted. You basically have to do a modulo of 10 of the number, and check if the value is 0, 1, 2, 8 or 9. You can put that in one `if`, and have just `return false;` in the `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the modulo of the given number is either less that or equal to 2 (`<= 2`), or greater than or equal to 8 (`>= 8`).

You don't have to check for any special values, since there aren't any, they respond to the general logic of the question.

```
public boolean neatTen (int num) {
    if (num%10 <= 2 || num%10 >= 8) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you had to take into account negative values, you would have to use `Math.abs()` to make the number positive, but that's a very small change to the code.

If you want to have it as a one-liner:

```
return (num%10 <= 2) ? true : (num%10 >= 8) ? true : false ;
```

Comment: simple version of above solution:

`public boolean nearTen(int num) {
  return (num%10<=2 || num%10 >= 8);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Return true if remainder after dividing by 10 is 0, 1, 2, 8 or 9.

```
public boolean nearTen (int num) {
    if (num%10 <= 2 || num%10 >= 8)
        return true;

    return false;    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I had understood the question right then you just need to use mod(%) and check if the reminder is <= 2 or >= 8.

```
public static boolean nearTen(int num) {
     if (num==10 || num==1){
          return true;
        }
      else if (num<10 && 10-num<2){
          return true;
          }
      else if (num%10<=2 || num%10>=8){
          return true;
          }
      else{
          return false;
          }     
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong. It will fail with 2, 18, 29, and many other numbers.

Comment: Yes, because 18 is within 2 of a multiple of 10, but doesn't pass your conditions as true.

Comment: Now all conditions are passed.